# Authorization: Bearer null

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, jwt, mern

I'm getting an error while trying to verify the token with jwt.verify.

I'm getting the token from here:

```
 `app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if user exists
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        error: 'No user found',
      });
    }

    // Check if password matches
    const match = await comparePasswords(password, user.password);

    if (match) {
      jwt.sign( {email: user.email, name: user.name}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: 86400}, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error signing JWT:", err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
        }

        res.cookie('token', token).json({ user });
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});`
```

Then, after logging in, the token is sent but when I go to the payload tab in Google Dev Tools this is what it gave me:

headers
:
{Authorization: "Bearer null", Content-Type: "application/json"}
Authorization
:
"Bearer null"
Content-Type
:
"application/json"

Now, after refreshing the page upon my login, in the network inspection tab, there will be an issue stating

''''
Request URL:
http://localhost:4000/profile
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:
[::1]:4000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
''''

And the JWT token isn't being grabbed.

This is the profile part in the index.js:

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  // Get the JWT token from the cookies
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(user);
})
});
```

UserContext.tsx:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext({ user: null }); // Inicializa con un objeto que tiene una propiedad user

interface UserContextProviderProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

export function UserContextProvider({ children }: UserContextProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // Inicializa con null

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === null) {
      Axios.get("/profile")
        .then(({ data }) => {
          setUser(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching user profile:", error);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Login.tsx:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigateTo = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (ev: any) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = data;

    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post("/login", {
        email,
        password,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      if (data.error) {
        toast.error(data.error);
      } else {
        setData({ email: "", password: "" });
        toast.success("Login successful");
        navigateTo("/");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, `localStorage.getItem("token")` will not exist, simply because you're setting the token as a cookie on the backend, and are not explicitly setting it in localStorage.

To get your version of the code to work with `cookies`, you need to tell axios to make cross-site Access-Control requests using credentials (eg cookies), by passing option `withCredentials` as true (is false by default). You can either:

1. Set the config via axios defaults, like so

```js
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

or

2. Create a new instance of axios, and use the instance to make requests, like so:

```js
const axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  withCredentails: true,
  // Other options
});
axiosInstance.get("...")
```

This way, `req.cookies.token` should exist on the backend